# wp_remote_get keeps timing out

Tags: plugin-development, wp-remote-get

I'm making a plugin that compares data from external API with meta items in WordPress backoffice.

I tried using `wp_remote_get` method to query my API but it doesn't return anything, nobody, nothing. When accessed directly with the same URL in browser the API generates JSON array without problems.

What am I doing wrong?

This is (partially omitted code in the plugin)

```
    ..........
    $chopped = explode("@", $meta['Email'][0]);

    $url = 'http://example.com/api/users/'.$chopped[0].'/'.$chopped[1];

    global $wp_version;
    $args = array(
        'timeout'     => 5,
        'redirection' => 5,
        'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'user-agent'  => 'WordPress/' . $wp_version . '; ' . home_url(),
        'blocking'    => true,
        'headers'     => array(),
        'cookies'     => array(),
    ); 
    $response = wp_remote_get( $url, $args );
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
    $http_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response );

    echo '<pre> Test dump: '.print_r($http_code,1).'</pre>';
```

edit 1: For those who might think it has to do with csrf protection or similiar, I can query the api from https://www.hurl.it/ without any problems too.
Could the error be because I'm calling it inside a hook?

edit 2: The response code I'm getting

```
WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
             [http_request_failed] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Connection timed out after 5003 milliseconds
                )

        )

    [error_data] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: Did you try to increase the timeout?

Comment: Yes I did (lowered it back to 5s because I was running out of patience), but the response body has only few lines of code so it should be loaded pretty much instantly anyway.

Comment: If it's a public API, I would be happy to test it for you from here to see if it gives the same timeout issue.

Comment: Be my guest http://medi.eqr-system.com/api/test I'm going to ip whitelist it later anyway :)

Comment: Loaded in browser in less than sec. lets try the WP remote get

Comment: `$response = wp_remote_get( 'http://medi.eqr-system.com/api/test' ); die( var_dump( $response['body'] ) );` and the output in my browser: `string '{"testkey":"testvalue","testkey2":"testvalue2","testkey3":"testvalue3"}' (length=71)`

Comment: You're saying it works?

Comment: Perfectly. I can load the same result via url, and also by doing: `wp_remote_get( $url );`

Comment: The same exact code doesn't work in my plugin though. How do I get just the array to work with in php?

Comment: I'm hooking this function in        add_action('woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta', 'the_function'); if that helps

Comment: Ah I think I know why, i think the request is creating an infinite loop of some sort because the API endpoint is created on init also for your wordpress.

Comment: Any way around that?

Comment: I'm getting the same result with simple api on my localhost once I reach a solution I am going to post it here.

Comment: Can you try to add a check that won't load the API if a specific API endpoint was not found? that should stop the loop?

Comment: How can I do that? I'm pretty much enveloping a test array in codeigniter-restservers $this->response() method. There's no logic going on there.

Comment: Which option could help? https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/blob/master/application/config/rest.php Oh and appending ".json" or ".xml" changes the output.

Comment: Any luck so far? I'm googling all day for a possible solution but there's nothing

Answer (score 9):

Check with these args

```
$args = array(
    'timeout'     => 10,
    'sslverify' => false
);
```

Comment: The default timeout is 5 seconds.

Comment: sslverify is what fixed it for me - i suddenly got a timeout even though it was set to 15 seconds, and the api was on the same server. also, the ssl certificate is valid.

Answer (score 2):

just **set a timeout argument** for that.

```
wp_remote_get('Your Rest API URL', ['timeout' => 20]);
```

or you can also set it in the `functions.php` file:

```
function custom_timeout_extend( $time )
{
    return 20;
}

add_filter( 'http_request_timeout', 'custom_timeout_extend' );
```